# Backup WD My Cloud outside local network

Tags: backup, nas, remote, cloud-storage

Is there any way, easy or hard, to keep my WD My Cloud NAS backed up from a remote network? I understand that the built-in Safepoints function only works locally, right? All I want is a hard drive on another location with an automatically updated mirror of my WD My Cloud NAS.

Comment: (Just FYI: see my comment to Techpumpkin's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you can use www.wd2go.com to mount remote shares on your work computer and manually sync/copy files from these shares or you can set up the cloud as an FTP server, then make the FTP access available remotely.

Comment: It seems a community post [Alternative to Safepoint](https://community.wd.com/t/alternative-to-safepoint-reposted/140685) might work well, if the remote server supports rsync.